# ERROR: column reference is ambiguous

Tags: sql, postgresql

ERROR: column reference "b_id" is ambiguous

знаю что данная ошибка означает что нужно изменить где-то b_id, но что-то не могу понять где.

Вот запрос:

```
SELECT "b_id","b_genre","b_author","b_book_name","b_page_count","at_text","bc_name" FROM "book" LEFT JOIN "annotation" ON "b_id"="at_bid" LEFT JOIN "book_cover" ON "bc_book_id"="b_id" LEFT JOIN (SELECT "b_id" FROM "book" ORDER BY "b_id" DESC OFFSET 10 LIMIT 10 ) as t ON t.b_id = "book".b_id
```

Ошибка которая вываливается:

```
ERROR: column reference "b_id" is ambiguous LINE 1: SELECT "b_id","b_genre","b_author","b_book_name","b_page_cou... ^
```

Вот это, я использую как offset, limit так как если использовать прямой offset и limit запрос зависает конкретно, записей много.

```
LEFT JOIN (SELECT "b_id" FROM "book" ORDER BY "b_id" DESC OFFSET 10 LIMIT 10 )
```

База данных PostgreSQL 9.3.11

Comment: у вас b_id есть в нескольких таблицах укажите в select `tablename.b_id` скорее всего, все получится

Comment: Кстати, `LEFT JOIN (SELECT "b_id" FROM "book" ORDER BY "b_id" DESC OFFSET 10 LIMIT 10 ) as t
       ON t.b_id = "book".b_id` вообще никак не влияет на выполнение запроса. потому как из первого book записи будут выбраны вне зависимости от того, что в этом подзапросе. Ибо left так работает.

Comment: @Mike спасибо. Поправил на JOIN.

Answer (score 7):

При наличии двух таблиц (или запроса одной и той же таблицы), в которых есть поле "b_id" SQL выдаст ошибку которая дословно звучит как "Поле `b_id` неоднозначно", понимать ее надо так: SQL не знает какое из двух значений вывести пользователю.

Валидным методом решения данной проблемы является точное указание какое из двух значений вы хотите получить.

```
SELECT t."b_id","b_genre","b_author","b_book_name","b_page_count","at_text","bc_name" 
FROM "book" 
LEFT JOIN "annotation" ON "b_id"="at_bid" 
LEFT JOIN "book_cover" ON "bc_book_id"="b_id" 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT "b_id" FROM "book" ORDER BY "b_id" DESC OFFSET 10 LIMIT 10 ) as t 
ON t.b_id = "book".b_id
```

или

```
SELECT "book"."b_id"
```

Comment: Теперь все работает адекватно. `SELECT "book"."b_id","book"."b_genre","book"."b_author","book"."b_book_name","book"."b_page_count","at_text","bc_name" FROM "book" LEFT JOIN "annotation" ON "b_id"="at_bid" LEFT JOIN "book_cover" ON "bc_book_id"="b_id" JOIN (SELECT "b_id" FROM "book" ORDER BY "b_id" DESC OFFSET 0 LIMIT 10 ) as t ON t.b_id = "book".b_id LIMIT 10` У меня просто все запросы формируются через php класс.

Comment: Использование второго SELECT обращающегося к той же таблице, в принципе является нарушением логики построения запроса SQL. Теоретически это неправильный ход, и использование ORDER BY "b_id" DESC OFFSET 0 LIMIT 10 должно быть в первоначальной выборке, тогда подобной ошибки не возникнет. Почему у вас этот вопрос работает во много раз быстрее, чем валидный проверить не могу.